# Who do I contact when I find an external site infringing the content of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, licensing

I found this site, https://www.javaer101.com, which appears to be ripping off the content of Stack Overflow.

**Stack Overflow page**: [How to add multiple security groups and group names in cloudformation using template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542580/how-to-add-multiple-security-groups-and-group-names-in-cloudformation-using-temp)

**External site page**: https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/12739519.html

To make matters worse, the site author is acknowledging its infringement at the bottom of the page.

> Collected from the Internet 
> Please contact javaer101@gmail.com to delete if infringement.

Who do I contact at Stack Overflow when I come across content infringement?

Comment: @Jeanne Dark It does answer my question. Should I remove this post?

Comment: @CaleSweeney no need, you can keep it. After all this is a unique site that you found.

Comment: @CaleSweeney - let it serve as a signpost for others who find that site in the future (if it still exists). What you did is actually a service to the health of the platform we are all on, so keep it up [no witch hunts, though, please] :)